# xtext keywords and terminal rule

Tags: xtext

I don t understand difference of keyword ('' ->single quotes) that is symbol and terminal symbol (''-> single quotes).Keywords are a kind of terminal rule literals .Please help me

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your question. What difference are you referring to? Keywords are terminal symbols, that are defined inline in production rules compared to terminal rules which offer more syntactic flexibility but cannot be defined inline.

Answer (score 0):

Keywords are a kind of terminal rule literals. The ID rule in org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals for instance starts with a keyword:
terminal ID : '^'? .. ;I take this pragraf from Xtext documentation.But we define terminal rule '' .
I do not understand '^' is keyword ? Also why use ""( double quates ) for keywords ?